# Memory problem in android at run time

Tags: java, android

I need to display many rows in `ListView` in my android application . There is more than 2500 rows with each row contains tow images and 11 labels . So I am getting memory error at run time like "VM will not lets you to use more than 120000 bytes" .

How can I solved this problem ?

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in holding all the information in memory at once. Your user can't see all the 2500 rows at a moment, so you should think about dynamically loading and unloading rows. Keep the info in an XML file and load it dynamically while your user scrolls the list.

Comment: How can i implements it ,dynamically loading and unloading rows when scrolling ??

Comment: Another thought is why don't you divide your list on some number of sublists? You can create a layout that will show your users some number of entries and will let them switch between pages, like on every site that has a list, eBay for example. They don't show all the rows, there are only 20, or 50 rows displayed.

Comment: Can You help me for how can i find currently visible views in scrollview ??

Comment: Sorry, don't have the straight away answer for you, take a look at the documentation.

Comment: @Egor let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1257/discussion-between-nirav-and-egor)